# Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 - My computer GUI - list of hard drives - "Unknown type"

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, hard-drive, gui

Please see attached image. I have no idea why it is being listed lik3 that. I have no problems with accessing the file system or any other problems. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to worry about. Nautilus just doesn't have a 'definition' for this type of link.

If it bothers you and you don't find the Type field useful you can turn it off by going to File->Preferences->List Columns and un-select the Type column or you could change the view mode from list to Icons.